# Animate position of items in CSS3 Column layout

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've created a CSS column layout with some rectangle `divs` inside. **[This is my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/AQ7bp/21/)**

When user clicks on each of them, it should remove. I've added CSS3 transition to it:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /*Safari & Chrome*/
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /* Firefox 4 */
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /* Opera */
transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
```

now the item which is clicked removes with effect, but other rectangles (after this div) changing their places without any effect.

How to add effect to other items when they are changing places? Is it possible with CSS3 Columns? If not, Which method should I prefer? How?

---

*Note: I'm going to create something like Windows 8 Start menu; when you remove a tile inside it, other items will move to their new position with animation.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the divs `display: block` and gave them `float: left`, is this the effect you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/AQ7bp/22/

Comment: Yes, this effect is almost what I'm looking for. But there is a problem: If you make transition longer (say, 3 seconds), you'll see that other tiles will not start moving until there is enough place for the text... (See this: http://jsfiddle.net/AQ7bp/25/ , *I'm using Chrome 23*) I've tried to replace that text with a `div` inside each tile, now tiles are moving immediately, but the `div` which is inside will be only in one side: http://jsfiddle.net/AQ7bp/23/   Any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by the `div` is only in one side, could you explain more? http://jsfiddle.net/AQ7bp/26/

Comment: If you put a div inside the main div, then the child div will place only on one side. see this: jsfiddle.net/AQ7bp/23 and this screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/fwoAt.png As you can see, half of red div (it's inside one of green divs) is not visible, but it should be visible in the next column...

Comment: I don't see that at all... I see all the numbers there just fine, see the example I linked previously (revision 26). Everything looks fine for me. Chrome 23 on Windows 7. What are you running?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 23 on Windows 8. Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/AQ7bp/27/ (This is almost like revision 26, but added `<br /><br />` to each tile) For me, text of tiles become invisible until they are fully fit in the right column.

Comment: I wonder if it's a bug on Win 8... everything still works fine for me. I see the text for all of the blocks at all times.

Answer (score 1):

I would surround each of your box with a container, with

```
{
overflow: hidden
max-height: 999px
display: inline-block
}
```

And animate this container to `max-height: 0` when removing a box. You could get the surrounding box with "parent". Then you let your box beeing animated:

```
surrounding-container {
transition: all 0.2s linear;
[..]
}
```

This will get the effect.

Edit:
Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sTBjn/

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to animate vertically. (I mean, 2 go to place of 1, 3 go to place of 2, 4 go to place of 3, etc.) Is it possible? (**See the order of 1,2,3,... in my fiddle**)